# How to neutralize candied glacé strawberry and kiwi

Tags: sugar, fruit, candy

I have 200 gm of candied glacé  strawberry and 200 gm of candied glacé kiwi. I cannot eat it, as it has too much sugar for me. Is there a way to neutralize the candied strawberry and kiwi?

Comment: ...don't eat them?

Answer (score 2):

Glacé, or candied fruit, is basically fruit preserved with sugar.  So, yes, it can be very sweet.  Even for sugar lovers, it is hard to eat much.  I would suggest using it in cake or cookies.  Italians have a tradition of such cakes and cookies that call for the addition of chopped candied fruit.  I am sure other cultures do as well. I would suggest using them as an ingredient, rather than attempting to somehow remove or reduce the sugar content.

Answer (score 1):

Strawberries and kiwi generally pair well with lemon or other citrus.

If the problem is just 'too sweet' and not truly a health concern (eg, diabetic), you might consider making a lemon tart (holding back some of the sugar), and topping it with the fruit.

... then sharing it with friends so you don't eat it all yourself.